# Motorcycle Maintenance

Tags: motorcycle, scheduled-maintenance, chain

What should you check/clean/replace on a Motorcycle?

I already:

- Change the oil (10w40) and filter twice a year
- Periodically check the tires for pressure, cracks, bumps (I forget the technical term), wear
- Lube the chain (I believe every 500km is the standard)
- Tension the chain

Other things I don't do, but maybe should:

- Carbs (clean/calibrate) - I'm a little scared to touch them since it's a 4 cylinder engine and I know you have to be very careful fooling around with the settings.
- Replace/clean air filter - I'm not sure how often to do this, but I don't think it has ever been done on my bike...
- Replace chain - I'm not sure how often this should be done, but I find my chain stretches a little more every year and has to be replaced occasionally
- Fork maintenance - I take it to a shop to have the fork seals fixed every time they start leaking, but I'm not sure if there's anything I can do to prolong their life.

This may be a community wiki kind of question, since there may be more than one correct answer, but I don't see the option.  Anything outside the accepted answer, I'll add to the question.

Comment: please visit http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3/making-a-site-for-professionals

Comment: @Michael Pryor, I'm not sure this question is opposed to the goal of the site.  There can be 1 right answer to the question, although I'd be happy to have more than 1 partial answer as well.  If you'd prefer, I could split it into the 4 most pressing questions I have (carbs, air filter, chain, and forks) and expand on them, but I don't want to spam the site with questions and it's the kind of CW thread that would probably prevent these same questions being asked over and over again.